# Debunking outlook email features with library win32com

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I found ways to check with python using library win32com for outlook the following attributes for any given email.

```
#imports:
import time
from time import strftime
import pandas as pd, win32com.client as client
from win32.com.client import Dispatch

#importing the excel file that contains email addresses and corresponding flags:
df_excel = pd.read_excel(r'\\user\...\addresses.xlsx')
#adding both columns as lists:
df_excel_mail = df_excel['mail'].tolist();df_excel_flag = df_excel['flag'].tolist()
outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')
main_account = outlook.Folders.Item(1)
folder_inbox = main_account.Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Test']
folder_inbox_WIP = main_account.Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Test'].Folders['WIP']

while True:
    time.sleep(0)
    messages = folder_inbox.Items.Count
    if messages > 0:
        for i in reversed(range(0,messages)):
            message = folder_inbox.Item[i]
            for y, z, in zip(df_excel_mail,df_excel_flag)
                if message.Categories == '' and y == message.SenderEmailAddress and z != 'nan'
                    message.Categories = z
                    message.Save
                    message.Move(folder_inbox_WIP)

    messages_v2 = folder_inbox_WIP.Items.Count
    if folder_inbox_WIP .Items.Count > 0:
        for ii in reversed (range(0,messages_v2)):
            message_v2 = folder_inbox_WIP[ii]
            message_v2.Move(folder_inbox)

    if strftime('%H, %M, %N') >= strftime('18:00:00')
        break
```

I would like to access for any given email:

1. receiver list (how would that work if I have more than one)?
2. cc list (" ")
3. Is there any other way to update the category on an email other than moving this email from a folder to another? I am working on a batch process and this moving in/out is slowing things.
4. When the email is sent from an email address "on behalf" of another email address how can I access the email on behalf?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `MailItem.Recipients` collection.
2. See #1 and check for each recipient's `Recipient.Type` property equal `olCC` ( =2)
3. Of course - set the `MailItem.Categpries` property. Don't forget to call `MailItem.Save`
4. Use the `MailItem.SenderEmailAddress`. For the sent on behalf of address, read the `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS` MAPI property. Access it using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001F")`

In general, take a look at various Outlook object using [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) to familiarize yourself with the Outlook Object Model.

Also keep in mind that to access a subfolder of the Inbox folder, it is better to use something like

```
out_iter_folder = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders['TEST']
```

where 6 is `olFolderInbox` constant.